# Combine streams with maximum time interval between values

Tags: c#, .net, linq, system.reactive

( Using [the Zip operator in Reactive Extensions (Rx)](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bnaya/archive/2010/03/05/rx-for-beginners-part-7-zip-expression.aspx) )

#### Combining Stream Pairs into One without Timeout

```
        var xyZipped = xStream.Zip(yStream, (x, y) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Latest Pair Has Arrived");
            return new List<SomeType> { x, y };
        });
```

- But how could you introduce a maximum allowed time interval between the two values in each stream, so that if the inter-value interval is exceeded then no value would be output from `xyZipped`
- And if too long passes between the two values **then pairing should be reset as well** i.e. for another pairing to occur after a timeout a new value should be produced in each of the streams (not just one).
- *Or would it be better to use a different operator / implementation to achieve this kind of stream logic?*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does reactive extensions support rolling buffers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597773/does-reactive-extensions-support-rolling-buffers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use Rx combinators. Since, your primary aim is `Zip`, let's start with `Zip`, and then apply your expiry conditions.

```
public static IObservable<TOut> ZipWithExpiry<TLeft, TRight, TOut>(
                    IObservable<TLeft> left, 
                    IObservable<TRight> right, 
                    Func<TLeft, TRight, TOut> selector, 
                    TimeSpan validity)
        {
            return Observable.Zip(left.Timestamp(), right.Timestamp(), (l, r) => Tuple.Create(l, r))
                             .Where(tuple => Math.Abs((tuple.Item1.Timestamp - tuple.Item2.Timestamp).TotalSeconds) < validity.TotalSeconds)
                             .Select(tuple => selector(tuple.Item1.Value, tuple.Item2.Value));
        }
```

If you want to check the adjacent values in a stream, you can rewrite it using `TimeInterval` operator instead of `Timestamp`.

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution! Turned out i needed `CombineLatest` instead of `Zip` for my purposes, so below is a slightly modified extension method that tested good for me: `public static IObservable<TOut> CombineWithExpiry<TLeft, TRight, TOut>(this
                    IObservable<TLeft> left,
            IObservable<TRight> right,
            Func<TLeft, TRight, TOut> selector,
            TimeSpan validity)`

Comment: `{
            return left.Timestamp().CombineLatest(right.Timestamp(), Tuple.Create)
                             .Where(tuple => (tuple.Item1.Timestamp - tuple.Item2.Timestamp).Duration().TotalMilliseconds < validity.TotalMilliseconds)
                             .Select(tuple => selector(tuple.Item1.Value, tuple.Item2.Value));
        }`

Comment: @Cel Great! I didn't know what exactly you meant by interval between values, so I took it for the interval between two successive values. Still, it's good you found your solution.