# Observable wait until no more changes for time x and then notify

Tags: c#, observable, system.reactive, reactiveui

I have a `TextBox` which acts like a `search field`. If a user types in a character, the `TextChanged event` is triggered immediately (**after every character input!**) and a long database operation is triggered.

What I want to do is, wrap that `event` into an `observable`, combine it with a `delay` that lasts until there are no changes for 500ms and then triggers only for **1 time**.

This is what I have so far, but I don't know how or what logic I have to add that it only pushes the last input.

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<TextChangedEventHandler, TextChangedEventArgs>(
    h => SearchField.TextChanged += h,
    h => SearchField.TextChanged -= h)
    .Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
    .Subscribe(args =>
    {
        // long database operation
    });
```

Found the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9791385/6229375

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: Yes I have edited my question and added the answer link (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9791385/6229375). Maybe the `BufferUntilInactive()` function can be added into the reactive source. 