# Rx Buffer reset if new request is in between current time span

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I am using Rx `Buffer` to club the operation for 2 seconds. But I want to reset the timespan counter if new request comes before time span expires.

```
_Event.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000))
    .Where(obj => obj.Count > 0)
    .Subscribe(this._Observer);
```

i.e

The first request came at 12:00PM and new request came at 12:01, then I want to reset the timespan for another next 2 seconds and so on. If there is no request for continuous 2 seconds, then execute the `OnNext` of observer.

Comment: Is this question relevant? [Does reactive extensions support rolling buffers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597773/does-reactive-extensions-support-rolling-buffers)

Comment: Thanks, Yes Indeed I was looking for the same. Marked it duplicates.